# Best practices for automatically restarting failed background processes?

Tags: 14.04, background-process

I have some software (consul) that runs as an agent in the background and I want to make sure its running at all times.  This is the command I use to start the agent:

```
nohup consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect 1 \
-data-dir /tmp/consul \
-bind=$(hostname -i) \
-client=0.0.0.0 \
-node=$(hostname) \
-config-dir /etc/consul.d \
-ui-dir /opt/consul/ &
```

Right now I have a check that runs in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
while true; do
    if [ -z "$(ps aux | grep "consul agent" | grep -v grep)" ]; then 
        sh /etc/rc.local2; 
    fi;
    sleep 3;
done
exit 0
```

If the consul agent is ever stopped then `/etc/rc.local2` is started that runs:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
nohup consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect 1 \
-data-dir /tmp/consul \
-bind=$(hostname -i) \
-client=0.0.0.0 \
-node=$(hostname) \
-config-dir /etc/consul.d \
-ui-dir /opt/consul/ &

exit 0
```

This system works, the issue is that it requires the servers I provision (all running various other forms of consul servers and clients) to be restarted before it really takes effect.  Even if I run `sudo nohup /etc/rc.local &` consul will still fail occasionally.

This was just a solution I created, but I definitely know its not the best solution I could be using.  What is the best way to check and insure that this process is always running?